# Proving product of two projection matrices is commutative

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression, projection-matrices

I’ve been trying to understand the details of orthogonal projections within the context of linear regression models, and I’ve come across the following scenario:

> Given a linear regression model $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\epsilon$ where $X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} \\ 1 & x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} \\ 1 & x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} \end{pmatrix} $ and $ \beta = \begin{pmatrix} \beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \\ \beta_2 \end{pmatrix} $,
> consider the projection matrix onto the column space of $X$, $H=X(X’X)^{-1}X’$. We define matrix $\tilde X $ as a matrix composed of *some* columns of $X$, and $\tilde H$ as the projection matrix onto the column space of $\tilde X$. i.e. without loss of generality $\tilde X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_{1,1}  \\ 1 & x_{2,1} \\ 1 & x_{3,1} \end{pmatrix} $ and $\tilde H=\tilde X(\tilde X’\tilde X)^{-1}\tilde X’ $.
> Formally prove that $\tilde H HY = \tilde HY$.

We’re additionally given a hint, to first prove that $H\tilde H= \tilde H$.

I have shown that $\tilde H HY = \tilde HY$ by a simple approach:

The projection of $Y$ onto $span(X)$ is given by $\hat Y= HY$. So $e=Y-\hat Y \in span(X)^{\perp}$ (due to the definition of an orthogonal projection, or one can easily show that $H(Y-HY)=0$ because $H$ is idempotent).

Then $\tilde H HY -\tilde HY = \tilde H (HY-Y) = \tilde H(\hat Y-Y) = -\tilde He $

Since $span(\tilde X) \subseteq span(X)$ it implies that for every $v\in span(\tilde X): e \perp v \implies \tilde He= 0$.

Thus, $\tilde H HY -\tilde HY = - \tilde He = 0 \implies \tilde HH = \tilde H$.

I don’t believe this was the author’s intention, due to the explicit definitions of the model and design matrix, as well as the given hint. Perhaps we should rigorously prove that the product of the projection matrices is commutative.

The fact that $H\tilde H= \tilde H$ is much more intuitive to me, and I’ve proved it in a similar fashion, considering properties of orthogonal projections and the fact that $span(\tilde X) \subseteq span(X)$.

I would love to hear your thoughts on this, how do I rigorously prove that $\tilde H HY = \tilde HY$, given that $H\tilde H= \tilde H$?

Comment: Given these are orthogonal projections, and hence self-adjoint, you can get between $H\tilde{H} = \tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{H}H = \tilde{H}$ easily:$$H\tilde{H} = \tilde{H} \iff (H\tilde{H})^* = \tilde{H}^* \iff \tilde{H}^*H^* = \tilde{H}^* \iff \tilde{H}H = \tilde{H}.$$

Comment: note that in your example $H$ is $3 \times 3$ idempotent with rank 3, so $H=I$.

Comment: Thank you for your insights, I appreciate it very much. The very specific details involving the design matrix $X$ and $\tilde X$ baffle me though, as if perhaps they want a manual proof of the initial claim, yet I don’t see how this is achievable. I hope this is sufficient.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "manual proof" but in general when $\text{image} \tilde X \subseteq  \text{image} X$ you can directly show $H\tilde H= \tilde H=\tilde HH$ via a bilinear form argument.  Let $\big\{\mathbf z_1, \dots \mathbf z_n\big\}$ be an orthornormal set of eigenvectors for $\tilde H$, and confirm $\mathbf z_i^T H\tilde H\mathbf z_k = \mathbf z_i^T\tilde H\mathbf z_k=\mathbf z_i^T \tilde HH\mathbf z_k$ for all $i,k$ (in particular it is $=1$ iff  $i= k$ and $ \mathbf z_i \in \text{image } \tilde H$ and $=0$ otherwise).

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you so much for your detailed response, both of your arguments were very helpful :)